# One query to count # of Oppos Closed Won and # Closed Lost

Tags: soql

How do i get this into one query ? I need to count total no of opportunities which are closed won and closed lost . Have written two queries and want to make it one with one variables .

```
      public integer Y
      {
        get
       {
          return Y;
       }
       set
       {
          String q='select COUNT(id) from opportunity where StageName=\'Closed Won\'';
          Y=Database.countQuery(q);
          System.debug('check Y' + Y);
       }

       }    

   public integer X
  {
  get
   {
      return X;
   }
  set
  {
      String q='select COUNT(id) from opportunity where StageName=\'Closed Lost\'';
      X=Database.countQuery(q);
      System.debug('Check X' + X);
  }

   }
```

I'm sorry, it was a typo . Want it with one query and one variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Set<String> stageNames = new Set<String>('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost');

String q = 'SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName IN ' + stageNames;

Y = Database.countQuery(q);
```

Updated with your intention to make the code as clean as possible, I've shipped the query out to a helper method:

```
public integer Y {

    get {

        return Y;

    } set {

        Y = xySetter(y);
    }
}    

public integer X {

    get {

        return X;

    } set {

        X = xySetter(x);
    }
} 

private Integer xySetter (String char) {

    Integer retInt = 0;

    if (char == 'X' || char == 'Y') {

        String q = 'SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = ';

        if (char == 'X') {

            q += '\'Closed Lost\'';

        } else if (char == 'Y') {

            q += '\'Closed Won\'';
        }

        retInt = Database.countQuery(q);        
    }

    return retInt;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me with the modification in my code with the help of this code . Where do i place this  ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'Have written two queries and want to make it one with one variables .'

Comment: I've given two variables X and Y for Closed won and Closed lost .The objective is to minimise my code with one variable and one query and your query can work but how can i make it ? Also modified my question. Thanks

Comment: Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding of your question, you would like to 'combine' the queries into a single query. You can do that by using the 'IN' clause of SOQL. After that you could just sort them manually in a for-loop.

Here's an example.

```
public class TestClass {

    public Integer Y {
        get; set;
    }

    public Integer X {
        get; set;
    }

    public TestClass() {

        List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName IN ('Closed Lost', 'Closed Won')];

        Integer lostCount = 0;
        Integer wonCount = 0;

        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') {
                lostCount++;
            }

            if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
                wonCount++;
            }
        }

        Y = wonCount;
        X = lostCount;

    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT Count(ID), StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName IN ('Closed Won','Closed Lost') GROUP BY StageName` or even `SELECT Count(ID), IsWon FROM Opportunity WHERE IsClosed = TRUE GROUP BY IsWon`

Answer (score 1):

I think that your query is these

```
String q = 'Select count(Id) number , IsWon FROM Opportunity WHERE IsClosed = true group by IsWon';
```

Comment: your query is working but how would i make it to one variable ?